Sum of reciprocal Bernoulli numbers
What is sum of the Bernoulli numbers? discusses the sum of the Bernoulli numbers, using divergent sum methods since the Bernoulli numbers grow exponentially. This exponential growth makes it so that the sum of the reciprocals of the (even index) Bernoulli numbers DOES converge
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{B_{2n}}.$$
Has this sum, or the more general power series/generating function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{B_{2n}}$ been studied? Is there a closed form? I notice that all the series involving the Bernoulli numbers (say on Wikipedia) have them in the numerator of the terms of the sum, so perhaps having the Bernoulli numbers in the denominator of terms in the sum is something new and exciting.

You might look at OEIS sequence A300220, but there's nothing exciting there.  If there is a closed form, it was apparently not known to the author of the sequence or the OEIS editors involved with it.

There is a series mentioned on the Wikipedia page that has the Bernoulli numbers in the denominator: the Riesz function.  See the subsection "A restatement of the Riemann hypothesis".

It isn't too hard to show that your power series is equivalent to $$\sum_{m\geq 1}\mu(m)\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{m}\right)$$ for complex $x$ (where $\mu(m)$ is the Mobius function). I certainly wouldn't call that a closed form, but I would not expect much more than that to exist. Do tell me if you would like a short derivation of this result as an answer.

@ChristianE.Ramirez sure, a derivation would be good to see

This function does intimately relate to the Riesz function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_function.

I doubt a true closed form for either the sum or the power series exists, though it is not too difficult to derive the following alternative representation for the power series, valid for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.
$$\boxed{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n}}{B_{2n}}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\mu(m)\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{m}\right)}$$
where $\mu(m)$ is the Möbius function.
To see this, we may use the identity $\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}B_{2n}}{2(2n)!}$ for $n\geq 1$, and the Dirichlet series $\frac1{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m^s}$ for $\mathfrak{R}(s)>1$ to proceed as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n}}{B_{2n}}&=-\frac12\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{(2\pi x)^{2n}}{(2n)!\zeta(2n)}\\
&=-\frac12\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{(2\pi x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m^{2n}}\\
&=-\frac12\sum_{m\geq 1}\mu(m)\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{(2\pi x/m)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=-\frac12\sum_{m\geq 1}\mu(m)(\cos(2\pi x/m)-1)\\\
&=\sum_{m\geq 1}\mu(m)\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{m}\right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Nicer than expected. Shouldn't this give a new expression for the Bernoulli numbers in terms of the mobius function?

@Nolord I don't think so, unless I'm missing something. Ultimately this just reduces to those two identities I mentioned at the top of the answer, which does give an expression for $\frac1{B_{2n}}$ as a series involving the Mobius function, but I don't think I'd call it new.
